# Precision of `rand()` function in Hive?

Tags: hive

If my table has many many rows, say tens of billion, would `select rand() from table` gives two same results for two rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `rand()` function in hive is `double`. The precision of double is approximately in range -10^308 to 10^308. So the chances of rand() returning a duplicate result is almost zero.

Tested the below query on hive with 15 billion rows.

```
 select r, count(*)
 from (
   select rand() as r from <table name>
 ) as a
  group by r 
  having count(*)>1;
```

The result was `No Rows Found`. This indicates `rand()` returned no duplicate rows.

Check this link from Hive wiki on [floating point precision](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-FloatingPointTypes).